# WSO2 ISKM 5.7.0 - mysql secondary UserStore - autoReconnect property does not work

Tags: wso2-identity-server

mysql `autoReconnect` property in the connection url of the User Stores -> Add (JDBCUserStoreManager) does not work. There are many of this errors in wso2carbon.log

> Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: The last
>   packet successfully received from the server was 720,434 milliseconds
>   ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 720,436
>   milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of
>   'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing
>   connection validity before use in your application, increasing the
>   server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J
>   connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>           at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
>           at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
>           at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
>           at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
>           at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.send(NativeProtocol.java:570)
>           at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendCommand(NativeProtocol.java:625)
>           at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendQueryPacket(NativeProtocol.java:941)
>           at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendQueryString(NativeProtocol.java:887)
>           at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.execSQL(NativeSession.java:1073)
>           at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:2046)
>           ... 162 more Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
>           at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:115)
>           at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
>           at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.writeBuffer(OutputRecord.java:431)
>           at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.write(OutputRecord.java:417)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecordInternal(SSLSocketImpl.java:879)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:850)
>           at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
>           at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
>           at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
>           at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketSender.send(SimplePacketSender.java:55)
>           at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketSender.send(TimeTrackingPacketSender.java:50)
>           at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.send(NativeProtocol.java:561)
>           ... 167 more

But if you configure this secondary user store manually in user-mgt.xml pointing at a datasource defined in master-datasources.xml with autoReconnect=true it works. But now when you try to access User Stores -> List from the carbon panel, you get this JSPException:

> TID: [-1234] [] [2020-03-27 23:52:53,669] ERROR
>   {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver} -  Exception
>   occurred while trying to invoke service method
>   getSecondaryRealmConfigurations
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
>           at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
>           at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
>           at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:170)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:82)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.local.CarbonLocalTransportSender.finalizeSendWithToAddress(CarbonLocalTransportSender.java:45)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender.invoke(LocalTransportSender.java:77)
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
>           at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:441)
>           at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:227)
>           at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration.stub.UserStoreConfigAdminServiceStub.getSecondaryRealmConfigurations(UserStoreConfigAdminServiceStub.java:1111)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration.ui.client.UserStoreConfigAdminServiceClient.getActiveDomains(UserStoreConfigAdminServiceClient.java:59)
>           at org.apache.jsp.userstore_005fconfig.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:194)
>           at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>           ...... Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration.beans.RandomPassword.setPassword(RandomPassword.java:58)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration.UserStoreConfigAdminService.getRandomPasswordProperties(UserStoreConfigAdminService.java:909)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration.UserStoreConfigAdminService.getSecondaryRealmConfigurations(UserStoreConfigAdminService.java:141)
>           ... 140 more TID: [-1234] [] [2020-03-27 23:52:53,677] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher} -  Servlet.service()
>   for servlet bridgeservlet threw exception
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
>           at org.apache.jsp.userstore_005fconfig.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:374)
>           at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>           ...... TID: [-1234] [] [2020-03-27 23:52:53,688] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver} -  Exception
>   occurred while trying to invoke service method
>   getSecondaryRealmConfigurations
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
>           at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
>           at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
>           ...... Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration.beans.RandomPassword.setPassword(RandomPassword.java:58)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration.UserStoreConfigAdminService.getRandomPasswordProperties(UserStoreConfigAdminService.java:909)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration.UserStoreConfigAdminService.getSecondaryRealmConfigurations(UserStoreConfigAdminService.java:141)
>           ... 136 more TID: [-1234] [] [2020-03-27 23:52:53,694] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher} -  Servlet.service()
>   for servlet bridgeservlet threw exception
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
>           at org.apache.jsp.userstore_005fconfig.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:374)
>           at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
>           ...... TID: [-1234] [] [2020-03-27 23:52:53,695] ERROR {org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext} -  JSPException
>   while including path '/userstore_config/index.jsp'.
>   javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: ServletException while including page.
>           at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil.doInclude(JspUtil.java:102)
>           at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:88)
>           at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:82)
>           at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:465)
>           at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:140)
>           at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:117)
>           at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:171)
>           at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75)
>           at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80)
>           at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f7(template_jsp.java:737)
>           at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspService(template_jsp.java:400)
>           at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>           ...... Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /userstore_config/index.jsp at
>   line 206
>
> 203:                  204:                  205:
>    206:                 <% if (userStoreDTOs[0] != null) { 207:
>   for (UserStoreDTO userstoreDTO : userStoreDTOs) { 208:
>   String className = userstoreDTO.getClassName(); 209:
>   String description = userstoreDTO.getDescription();
>
> Stacktrace:
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:580)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>           ......
>           ... 91 more Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
>           at org.apache.jsp.userstore_005fconfig.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:374)
>           at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
>           ... 113 more

Affected Product Version: ISKM 5.7.0
OS: Linux 5.0.0-1032-azure
MySql version: 5.7.27
JDBC Driver: mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar

Comment: Rather than using the autoReconnect property, you can configure the validation query and validation interval to get rid of stale connections in the connection pool.

Comment: Hi @Maduranga Siriwardena, thanks for your response. I had already configured "validationQuery for the database" = SELECT 1 and "Validation Interval(time in milliseconds)" = 30000 but the Connection reset error persists.

Comment: What is the validity of the connection from the database end?

Comment: connect_timeout: 10 / interactive_timeout: 28800 / wait_timeout: 120